# 'find' -perm example in doc

Tags: permissions, find, documentation

I was reading the official documentation of find online [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size). And I came across the following part (and I'm bolding the bolded part):

> ‘-perm -444 -perm /222 ! -perm /111’
>
> Match files that are readable for
> everybody, have at least one write bit set (i.e., somebody can write
> to them), but that cannot be executed/searched by anybody. Note that
> in some shells the ‘!’ must be escaped;.
>
> ‘-perm -a+r -perm /a+w !
> -perm /a+x’
>
> As above.
>
> **‘-perm -g+w,o+w’**
>
> **As above.**

I think the last example isn't the same as the first two. It shouldn't be *as above*. It should go like "Match files that are writable by their group **and** everyone."

Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @don_crissti, Done. Thanks. Link here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54838

Comment: The other bug you are pointing to has already been reported here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50758

Comment: Please put your command as answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a misplaced example... it should be right above the stuff you quoted and below

> `-perm -022`
>   Match files that are writable by both their owner and
>   their group.

which, by the way, is the wrong description for `022` (per your comment above that has already been reported and fixed)...

The final version should be something like

> `-perm -022`
>   Match files that are writable by both their group and everyone else.
>   `-perm -g+w,o+w`
>   As above.

Comment: Issue fixed. Check the link: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54838.
I have a question though. Where did they fix it? I mean, I went to the documentation page and the issue is still there. Also, doesn't them fixing the issue mean it should be propagated to the linux distros repo?

Comment: @joker - It's fixed in the git, it will take some time until they release the next stable version of `findutils` which contains the fixes (and which is most likely the source for that online doc page ) and only then will it "propagate" to the distros repos... Usually between 3 and 12 months (I'm not familiar with their release cycle though).